# How to resolve Python package dependencies with pipenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, dependencies, pipenv

I am using [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) to handle Python package dependencies.

The Python package is using two packages (named `pckg1` and `pckg2`) that rely on the same package named `pckg3`, **but from two different versions**. Showing the dependency tree :

```
$ pipenv graph
  pckg1==3.0.0
    - pckg3 [required: >=4.1.0]
  pckg2==1.0.2
    - pckg3 [required: ==4.0.11]
```

An attempt to install dependencies :

```
$ pipenv install

Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
You can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
Could not find a version that matches pckg3==4.0.11,==4.1.0,>=4.1.0 (from -r C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv-o7uxm080-requirements\pipenv-hwekv7dc-constraints.txt (line 2))
Tried: 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 3.3.3, 3.4.0, 3.4.2, 4.0.0, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.4, 4.0.6, 4.0.6, 4.0.8, 4.0.8, 4.0.9, 4.0.9, 4.0.10, 4.0.10, 4.0.11, 4.0.11, 4.1.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.1, 4.3.0, 4.3.0
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies.
```

As suggested, `pip install --skip-lock` does the trick, but the dependency tree is still unresolved.

I would love to tell `Pipenv` to override `pckg2`'s requirement, and specify `pckg3>=4.1.0`.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I get that error constantly. Clearing the cache in the lock file works beautifully every time.

`$ pipenv lock --pre --clear`

Comment: This is helpful, but I had to do it without the `--pre` or I got other mismatch errors.

Comment: combining @northtree with Harsha Goli did the trick......but still have no real understanding of what the underlieing issue was :(

Comment: It most often means there are invalid inconsistencies with the pipfile.lock. Sometimes this can genuinely happen if there is a dependency conflict - but this answer is tailored for when pipenv simply needs to dump it's cache and recreate the lock file

Comment: on my mac I can not use `pipenv lock --pre --clear` but it work only when i say `python3.9 -m pipenv lock --pre --clear` any help?

Comment: In my own situation I get the dependency error when I run `pipenv lock --pre --clear`.

Comment: ```
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches werkzeug<2.0.0,>=0.7,>=2.0 (from -r /var/folders/2y/061kgpfx29110d440z4w1ft40000gn/T/pipenvr4na45z1requirements/pipenv-ez8fnckw-constraints.txt (line 28))
Tried: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.4, 0.4.1, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.9.4, 0.9.5, 0.9.6, 0.10, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.10.2, 0.10.4, 0.10.4, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11.1, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.11.2, 0.11.3, 0.11.3, 0.11.4, 0.11.4, 0.11.5, 0.11.5, 0.11.6, 
...
```

Answer (score 21):

You can't. At the moment, `pipenv` doesn't offer anything for an explicit override of requirement constraints.

As a workaround, you can put dependencies that you want to override to `dev-packages` as those will be overridden by `packages`, so this `Pipfile` should install `pckg3>=4.1.0`:

```
# Pipfile
...
[packages]
pckg1 = "==3.0.0"

[dev-packages]
pckg2 = "==1.0.2"
```

If you now lock and install:

```
$ pipenv lock --dev
$ pipenv install --dev
```

the requirement `==4.0.11` will be overridden by `>=4.1.0`. This is ugly if you ask me because this is not what development packages are meant for and you're changing the role of `pckg2` dependency in project, but I don't see any better way here.

Comment: Overriding dependencies in `dev-package` works, but I really dislike putting non-dev packages in the dev packages list...

Comment: I agree that stinks (mentioned that in the answer), but I'm afraid there's no other option available with `pipenv`'s current development state...

Comment: @hoefling I don't understand how `3.0.0` and `1.0.2` is yaml are related to `==4.0.11 ` and  `>=4.1.0` in your explanation

Comment: @abhiieor check out the output of `pipenv graph` in the question - the first two are versions of direct dependencies, the last two are conflicting versions of the same transient dependency. Overall, this answer may be obsolete, I don't use `pipenv` anymore.

Answer (score 5):

This works when there are unfinished routines on pipfile.

Once I made a mistake and run

```
pipenv install codecove # With an 'e' at the end
```

and the pipenv kept always trying to complete the installation with no success because the lib does not exist. I resolved it with:

```
pipenv uninstall codecove
```

and installed codecov after.

I tried to run

```
pipenv lock --clear
pipenv lock --pre --clear
```

but only after uninstalled the lib with wrong name I succeeded.

Comment: Yes it's very stupid! Even if I try to install `pipenv install WrongName`: Of course, it will fail to install but in addition it will make `pipenv` unable to install everything after that! So i need to do after that: `pipenv uninstall WrongName`...

Answer (score 3):

I have the similar issue with `google-cloud-core`.

```
$ pipenv lock
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…

Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
Could not find a version that matches google-cloud-core<0.29dev,<0.30dev,>=0.28.0,>=0.29.0
Tried: 0.20.0, 0.20.0, 0.21.0, 0.21.0, 0.22.0, 0.22.0, 0.22.1, 0.22.1, 0.23.0, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.23.1, 0.24.0, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.1, 0.25.0, 0.25.0, 0.26.0, 0.26.0, 0.27.0, 0.27.0, 0.27.1, 0.27.1, 0.28.0, 0.28.0, 0.28.1, 0.28.1, 0.29.0, 0.29.0
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies.
```

It was solved by

1. rm -rf Pipfile.lock
2. pipenv update

Answer (score 2):

If you get an error like:

```
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
✘ Locking Failed!
```

For me, this happened because the underlying virtual environment did not refer to my current directory.

I solved this problem by moving the contents to a new directory and deleting the old one.

I also had to delete the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` but I'm not sure if that's necessary.

Comment: This works for me... but I don't feel great about it. Ha.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax yeah I agree. Wish I had transparency into the underlying problem

Answer (score 1):

It happened the same to me, I'm working with Visual Studio Code and I was able to get rid o it:

- remove all files except *.py from your python folder (.vscode, *pycache*, * virtual environments within that folder)
- create a new virtualenv env(name)
- new\scripts\activate.bat

and then try to install the missing dependencies for the virtual folder and good to go, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with glob module. I deleted `glob = "*"` from Pipfile and it worked fine after that.

Error:

```
bash-4.2# pipenv lock  --clear
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
✔ Success! 
Locking [packages] dependencies…
✘ Locking Failed! 
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 69, in resolve
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 395, in resolve
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches glob
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       No versions found
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches glob
No versions found
Was https://pypi.org/simple reachable?
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 395, in resolve
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches glob
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       No versions found
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches glob
No versions found
Was https://pypi.org/simple reachable?
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 using VS Code I got a clean install after much messing about by running pipenv in Powershell.  I also deleted all traces of the previous tries (new directory deleted the previous venvs).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing here worked for me. In the end this solved the issue:

```
pip uninstall pipenv
pip install pipenv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ran into the `Locking Failed!` error:

```
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
✘ Locking Failed!
```

**Clearing the cache** on `pipfile.lock`, **uninstalling** your package and **restarting the VM** did the trick for me.

Try:

```
pipenv uninstall *YourPackage*
pipenv uninstall *YourPackage* --dev   ##(if relevant to your package)
pipenv lock --clear
```

**stop & destroy VM**

**restart VM**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install -U pipenv
```

**solved for me**  on Ubuntu 21.04 - Hirsute Hippo - python Version 3.9.5

This command installed those packages:

- appdirs-1.4.4
- certifi-2021.5.30
- distlib-0.3.2
- filelock-3.0.12
- pipenv-2021.5.29
- six-1.16.0
- virtualenv-20.4.7
- virtualenv-clone-0.5.4

Answer (score 0):

Updating `pip` inside the virtualenv worked for me: `py -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

This could also be because you had an old pipenv environment and you need to clean it before you create a new one.

```
pipenv --rm
pipenv install
```

Answer (score -2):

```
pipenv lock
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…

Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
```

pipenv install --clean