# How to solve the incompatible versions issue of the transitive dependency google-resumable-media?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam, pipenv

I use the command `pipenv install ...` to install my python packages.

My problem:

If I install the python packages (**google-cloud-storage** and **google-auth-oauthlib**) and then if I try to install **apache-beam[gcp]**, I get the following exception :

```
pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches google-resumable-media<0.5.0dev,<0.6dev,>=0.3.1,>=0.5.0
...
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies.
```

And the same happens if I inverse the order : **apache-beam[gcp]** then (**google-cloud-storage** and **google-auth-oauthlib**)

How can I resolve the dependencies issue?

Maybe excluding transitive dependencies would resolve the problem? How to do that using Pipenv?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

By the error, it seems that removing these dependencies/libraries might fix your problem.

Searching around, I could find on this question in the [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54494286/how-to-fix-error-could-not-find-a-version-that-matches-install) a possible cause for your problem, in case you want more information about it.

I went to find a possible solution and I could find this post on the Community - [How to resolve Python package depencencies with pipenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540404/how-to-resolve-python-package-depencencies-with-pipenv) - where you can find all possible `pipenv` commands that could help you fix the issue. I would recommend you to take a look at it and give it a try on the possible fixes and codes.

Let me know if the information helped you!